# Как развернуть на Docker nginx + Python + NodeJS?

Tags: nginx, docker

Собственно, вопрос указан в заголовке. Как развернуть на Docker nginx + Python + NodeJS? Я новичок в этом, хотелось бы взять работающую связку.

Comment: Конфигурация будет сильно зависеть от того какие задачи вы собираетесь решать. Будет ли каждый сервис в своем контейнере или все в одном? Все от задачи зависит.

Comment: Допустим, API сервиса - на Node.JS, все остальное - Django.

Comment: + React в этой же экосистеме )

Answer (score 1):

Если в кратце, то лучше всего использовать docker-compose, где каждый контейнер будет отвечать за свой сервис. То есть будут отдельно контейнеры под nginx, python+django, postgres, nodejs и т.д.  Посмотрите, на гитхабе есть полно подобных примеров, вот один из них: https://github.com/phpdude/docker-django-webpack-skeleton